# SQL, search and replace specific characters in a column (switching "Z" & "Y")?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column `SN` with serial numbers like `FFMZR62TYY67`.

Is there a `SQL statement` to replace all `Y to Z` and all `Z to Y` = `FFMYR62TZZ67`?

thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgresql has a function "translate" for this kind of thing:

```
select translate(SN, 'YZ', 'ZY') from my_table;
```

Every character in the second argument will be replaced with the corresponding character in the third one.

Here ist the full documentation: [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)

Comment: `update table set SN = translate(SN, 'YZ', 'ZY');`
works perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
1st replace Y with 1 and Z with 2
and again replace 1 with Z and 2 with Y

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(SN,'Y','1'),'Z','2'),'1','Z'),'2','Y')

select replace(replace(replace(replace(SN,'Y','$1'),'Z','%1'),'$1','Z'),'%1','Y')
```

Comment: but its possible there is a 1 or 2 in the string, which should not be replaced.
Maybe it works with some special Characters (§"§$%)! thanks

Comment: so replace with some special character.

Comment: so the statement should look like
`update table set SN = replace(replace(replace(replace(SN,'Y','$'),'Z','€'),'$','Z'),'€','Y')` ? could this work?

Answer (score 1):

The [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement is what you are looking for.
Since you want to swap letters, you need to replace one letter by a dummy first.
Somwthing like this (untested):

```
UPDATE myTable t
SET SN = REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               t.SN,
               'Y',
               '?'),
             'Z',
             'Y'),
           '?',
           'Z')
```

? should not be in the original string

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `TRANSLATE` function...

```
declare @Input nvarchar(20) = N'FFMYR62TZZ67';
declare @Output nvarchar(20) = translate(@Input, N'YZ', N'ZY');
select [@Input]=@Input, [@Output]=@Output;
```

Resulting in:

```
@Input               @Output
-------------------- --------------------
FFMYR62TZZ67         FFMZR62TYY67
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(replace((replace('FFMZR62TYY67','Z','!')),'Y','Z'),'!','Y')
```